# Easiest way to declare a module public recursively

Tags: rust

Example

```
pub mod a {
 pub mod b {
  ...
 }
 pub fn c() {
  ...
 }
 ...
}
```

Is it possible to replace all the `pub`s with a single attribute or something like that?

Comment: Making an item public should always be a conscious decision, so Rust makes everything private by default. While you probably could implement a proc macro to make everything public recursively, you really shouldn't.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm only doing this for a very specific thing.

Comment: Why not just use an editor to replace `\nmod` with `\npub mod`?

Comment: Well, it's not just just modules, I am looking for something like a c header style import which doesn't have a namespace or a private scope.

Comment: So are you looking for [`std::include!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include.html)? If so , you should probably have asked the question in the comment rather than the question you did ask.